# create custom decoder page on godaddy host that fix querystring and redirects to an API

Tags: aws-lambda, cloud, host, godaddy-api

A friend contracted some wordpress agency to create a webpage that based on input data entered by user on a form create a custom URL to redirect to a third party API that shows some data to rent a car, this wordpress is done with elementor plugin and the problem is that when redirecting the query params separators are being encoded as html entities i.e the url must be something like `www.site.com/?value1=value1&value2=value2&value3=value3` but the plugin is changing the url to `www.site.com/?value1=value1&amp;value2=value2&amp;value3=value3` the `&` is being encoded to `&amp;`, this agency left the work unfinished and don't want and also can't fix this, he asked me if I can fix it, I am not a wordpress developer so have been difficult for me, in my desperation one idea arose to my mind, them have this site hosted on goddady I think I can code a custom decoder with regex that change the `&amp;` to `&` and then redirects with the corrected url to the the API that brings the car data, so the wordpress now won't redirect to `www.site.com/?...` which is the car rental API instead will redirect to the custom url decoder like `www.customdecoder.com/{wrong query params}`, so the question is if please you can explain me how can I host this custom decoder on goddady alongside the wordpress page? or should I better do this as a aws lambda function? if this is a lambda function could it cost a lot? please forgive me if this question is kinda weird but is not a wordpress question.