# PHP - How to get query params sent to script

Tags: php, query-string

A friend contracted some wordpress agency to create a webpage that based on input data entered by user on a form create a custom URL to redirect to a third party API that shows some data to rent a car, this wordpress is done with elementor plugin and the problem is that when redirecting the query params separators are being encoded as html entities i.e the url must be something like `www.site.com/?value1=value1&value2=value2&value3=value3` but the plugin is changing the url to `www.site.com/?value1=value1&amp;value2=value2&amp;value3=value3` the `&` is being encoded to `&amp;`, this agency left the work unfinished and don't want and also can't fix this, he asked me if I can fix it, I am not a wordpress developer so have been difficult for me, in other post someone said me that I can create a custom decoder php file to handle this on the rootfolder of the wordpress installation and instead of redirecting the form to the third party API I can redirect to the custom decoder on the site domain and fix the url to then redirect to the third party API  but I can't get the url sent by the form in the php script I have this code right now

```
<?php
ob_start();

$API_BASE_URL="www.site.com/";

$bad_url={here must be the url sent by the form};

//here is fixed the url
$good_url=html_entity_decode($bad_url);

//concatenation of API_BASE_URL and goodurl
$redirect_url=&API_BASE_URL.$good_url

//redirects to fixed url
header('Location: '.$redirect_url);

exit();
?>
```

Also i saw that the `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`  can be used to get this url but this is not reliable, so I need another way to get the url of the form, how can I do this? the form will now redirect to `www.misytedomain.com/custom-decoder/decoder.php/?value1=value1&amp;value2=value2&amp;value3=value3` that is the url I must use to build the url to send to the API.

**EDIT:**

srry if I am missexplaining for example, the form redirects right now to `www.site.com/?value1=value1&amp;value2=value2&amp;value3=value3` but this won't work on the API so I will instead of redirec to that URL redirect to the location on my domain where the php file is somethin like `www.mysitedomain.com/custom-decoder/decoder.php` I thought that I could add the wrong query params like `www.mysitedomain.com/custom-decoder/decoder.php/?value1=value1&amp;value2=value2&amp;value3=value3` take this wrong params, fix with the php logic and finally redirect to the API with correct params like `www.site.com/?value1=value1&value2=value2&value3=value3` `www.site.com` is the api and `www.mysitedomain.com` is my wordpress domain

Comment: Use https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php + https://stackoverflow.com/a/5397746/2585154

Comment: but how will I catch the url that is redirecting the form in the customdecoder.php, what I need is the url that the form is redirecting and this will change based on the inputs of this form

Comment: Could you explain a little more? Just step by step and what exactly do you want to get

Comment: srry if I missexplained. A form is sending wrong the query separators to a api So i created a php file that is intended to get fix the url and redirect to the api, so the form will not redirect to the API, instead will redirect to where the php file is inside my domain, this redirection will also have the bad query strings that will be fixed and then redirect to the API but i don't know how to get this url , see my edit please

Comment: So, you want to send wrong url to server (PHP), fix it and then redirect to correct url. Is it correct? And what exactly didn't work?

Comment: yes that is what I want but what didn't work is that I don't know how to catch this url

Comment: Could you share your HTML form code?

Comment: I mean something like <form action="...." method="...."><input type="hidden" name="broken_url" value="your broken url" /></form>

Comment: the problem is that is not a HTML form, is a plugin form that is sending the wrong url so instead of redirect to the api i will redirect to the path inside the domain where the php file is located

Comment: Okay, could you share what the plugin sends? Look for XHR request in your browser devtools

Comment: P.S. if you not sure, try to output var_dump($_REQUEST); in your PHP code

Comment: I can define where url the plugin send but the problem is that, the plugin encode the query params separator ```&``` to ```&amp;``` so the values of the form are not readed by the api, I need to fix this changing the ```&amp``` to `&` before

Comment: this is the first post I did and the answer i got [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74895214/create-custom-decoder-page-on-godaddy-host-that-fix-querystring-and-redirects-to/74895350](first question) this can clarify a lot what I mean here

Comment: Okay. Step 1: You say you can customize the URL where the user will be redirected to, so configure redirect to your PHP script. Step 2. Write var_dump($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); in your PHP script and show output

Comment: this returns ```string(27) "/custom-decoder/decoder.php"```, I used print to get this response

Comment: Don't forget to add broken query parameters to redirect url, I don't see them in your output

Comment: Oh i noticed, man this is the answer thanks a lot , please answer to select as correct, thanks you a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure a redirect from plugin to your own PHP script (don't forget to add your broken query parameters) and then access wrong query parameters in `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`